# MS Access guide

Tags: ms-access, vba, conditional-statements, expression, ms-access-2010

I am a newbie in MS Access. I have a Table 1 in MS access which contains column 1 and column 2. Also,I have a another empty table Table 2. On the click of a button, I have to perform some condition checks on Table 1 columns and based on the result, I have to insert entries into Table 2 programmatically.

If it was Oracle PL/SQL I would have written a stored procedure to write the entire set of code. In MS Access how do I achieve this?

Comment: Use the Query Design button (not the wizard), select Table1 and click the Append button on top. Then use the Query Designer to build your append query.

Comment: Hi Wouter,Thanks for your lightning speed reply. So I used the append option and the query designer which opened up had the 'insert into' query pre loaded. What I am trying to achieve is run through each record in Table 1 and do some checks like if column 1 value is mapped to only unique column 2 values and so on.. So in the query designer will i be able to write a cursor and then include condition checks and stuff ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create 2 queries: 1 for checking you conditions (filtering out the "good" rows) and 1 for updating. Then a little VBA procedure like this (untested) should do the trick, or at least give you a start:

```
sub DoMyJob()
   if dcount("*", "controlQueryName") > 0 then  'some controls failed
      docmd.openquery "controlQueryName"        'shows the bad rows
      msgbox "Check the source data"
   else
      docmd.openquery "updateQueryName"         'execute the append
   end if
end sub
```

Comment: This is where I am a bit confused, pardon my ignorance. Cant I write the entire logic in the query 1 itself (including if conditions and insert statements )and link it to a button or something ?

Comment: @JeffGodly: no. an Access query can only contain one statement. This is why you must "glue" them with either VBA or Macros. If you are a beginner with Access and VBA, you could rather try looking at the macros, which could be easier for your, and are a good way to learn Access programming possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a conditional insert if I'm understanding you correctly.

```
INSERT INTO tblOne (Field1)
SELECT Field1 FROM tblTwo WHERE Field2='MyCondition'
```